# rediremoving the.asp suffix from the url

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

how do I re-direct people to the i.e (http://super.cash.com/boom.asp) page after they click the i.e http://super.cash.com/boom url which does not have the .asp suffix at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule in your root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asp -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.asp [L]
```

**For 301 redirect:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.asp -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.asp [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, l'm new to web devpmnt so bare with me . Btw, is this the same as the 301 redirect or is it tottally different?

Comment: This is not 301 redirect. This is internal(silent) rewrite. If you want 301 redirect see edit above.